# Install SSL for a site in IIS 8 when you have a certificate.txt file and private key file

Tags: tls, iis

I have two files.

1. File whose contents start with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
2. File whose contents start with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

How do I use these two files to create a SSL for a given website in IIS 8/Windows Server 2012 R2

I have tried a few suggestions like useing OpenSSl and running this command:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out lcertificate.pfx -inkey private.key -in cert.crt -certfile CACert.crt

But I get an error : unable to load certificates

What am I doing wrong or is there a better way to install SSL certificates for IIS 8 Website using those two files.

Comment: use a certbot by lets encrypt?

Comment: This is not on-topic for this site, but the answer is you can't.  The first file is a certificate request file, not a certificate.  You need the file with the certificate that has the public key that is paired with your private key file.

Comment: sorry, I am a total noob to SSL. so certbot is a tool that will help me create a .pfx file using the above mentioned files?

Comment: @VipulNair There is no certbot for Windows.

Comment: ohh sorry then didnt know that.